# Memory Deallocating freezes my program

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

**This is not a problem, just a question that I want to be answered.**

I'm making 2D application that has particles. In the click handler I've written this code:

```
Particle *tempp = new Particle();
tempp->setPosition(mx, my);
particles.push_back(tempp); // typeof particles = std::list<Particle*>
delete tempp; // <- this line is the problem
```

When I click, one particle will be created at the mouse position. After about one second it should disappears, which works fine. After it's disappeared I can click again to create a new particle.

However, when I click while there still is one particle on the screen, my program freezes and stops working.

My *destructor* of the `Particle` class and it's parent's *destructor* are both empty.

WITHOUT calling `delete` my program runs fine, even with multiple particles at once, or even multiple per frame. I am just wondering what is causing this freezing issue.

Comment: You are adding a pointer to tempp to the vector - what does it point to after tempp is deleted?

Comment: Why are you pushing tempp into a list and then deleting it the line after? Your list contains pointer to garbage and any attempt to access them will probably cause your program to crash.

Comment: So the pointer to tempp still exists after the end of the method is reached? And if I delete it, the memory will be overwritten?

Comment: @Broxzier Your list is not local to the function and hence exists even outside the method. When you do delete the actual memory allocated is freed(available for re-use// it might be overwritten , just be there. BUT its not there for you to use and its UB to dereference it) the pointer still contains the address. list is  not out of scope so it still has the pointer with the address. You are probably dereferencing the `deleted` memory address (possibly for drawing the point on the screen or maybe tryin to erase it after the timeout and that freezes it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the posted code, the `particles` container will contain dangling pointers. Any attempt to dereference these is undefined behaviour. I am assuming they are later being used, otherwise the storage of them seems pointless.

Calling `push_back()` does not copy the pointed-to-object but copies the value of the pointer (the memory address of the dynamically allocated object). If `Particle` is cheap to copy, is copyable and polymorphic behaviour is unrequired just store the `Particle` in the container. Otherwise, suggest using a smart pointer, such as [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), to automatically destruct the `Particle` when removed from the container.

Comment: Why does creating a second point(while 1st one still exists) cause an issue? The click handler will be invoked at every call , it seems `tempp` is local to the function and a `new` memory allocation will take place. (I agree about the dangling pointers)

Comment: @SuvP, the first one does not exist as it has been `delete`d immediately. If the creation of the second `PArticle` accesses one of the dangling pointers in `particles` then is undefined behaviour, and the probable cause of the behaviour.

Comment: Looking at the current code and assuming nothing else happens elsewhere, The list is not utilised anywhere else. (The OP justs adds the address and deletes the memory //unrealistic i know)then it shouldnt be a problem? (apart from the dangling pointer). So maybe the OP is accessing the `list` somewhere else, that might be causing the issue? [Just want to clear my doubt properly ]

Comment: @SuvP, yes. Pointers to deallocated memory are not themselves a problem, you can print the address of a pointer that points to deallocated memory. What you cannot do is _dreference_ a pointer that points to deallocated memory (or unallocated memory). Somewhere else in the code it probably dereference one of the pointers added to the container.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what causes the problem now. The pointer in the vector is still there and being used, and creating a new Partcile will use that memory again?

Comment: @Broxzier, the rest of the code is unavailable to me but a bug would be any code that attempts to use (dereference) any of the pointers in `particles`.

Comment: @Broxzier You might be dereferencing the pointer to that address at some other portion of your code using the `list`.

Answer (score 3):

When you push the pointer into the list, you only push a copy of the actual pointer and do not make a copy of what it points to. This means that after the `push_back` you have *two* pointers pointing to the *same* memory.

If you then free that memory, then you have a pointer pointing to free memory, and that pointer is now invalid.

Answer (score 3):

When I see `new` and then a few lines later `delete`, I would rather see the stack used. Unless `Particle` is enormous (which I doubt) you could change your code to this:

```
Particle tempp;
tempp.setPosition(mx, my);
particles.push_back(tempp); // change particles to std::list<Particle>
```

Presto. You write less code and you won't blow up.

Comment: Thanks for answering. That works, ofcourse, but I wanted to know what was causing the problem in this situation, not a solution. Without calling delete or using changing the vector to store actual particles it already worked fine.

Comment: @Broxzier it didn't work fine, it just didn't blow up. Whatever you new, you must delete. Your code with new and no delete was leaking memory. These days we have a lot, so it doesn't hurt you, but it doesn't work fine. There is no reason to use the heap in this case and it's best to use good habits whenever you can. Stack semantics should always be your first choice in C++

Answer (score 2):

You are putting a `pointer` into the container and then deleting it which is a problem. `push_back` will copy the value of the `pointer` not the contents of the `pointer` so when you call `delete`, the `pointer` in the container is no longer valid. So now you have a dangling pointer and when you dereference it this will be undefined behavior but most likely a crash.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I believe, lies in your 3rd line of code. Note that particles is a vector of *pointers to Particles*? Well, in the 3rd line, you create a copy of the pointer and insert it into a list. On the very next line, you deallocate the memory that is pointed-to by that pointer. **The list does not store your particle - it merely stores the memory address of the particle** So, when you delete the particle, you tell the compiler to re-use the memory that contains your valid data.

So, while commenting the 4th line makes the problem go away, it's not actually crashing there - there's no reason for it to. The likely scenario is that it crashes when trying to do something with the memory that *used to be yours*, but was freed in line 3.

You could make the list store actual Particles as a fix.